# Andengine (gles2) - ButtonSprite don't react on click

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I have code like this:

```
mButton = new ButtonSprite(400  , 400, myTiledTextureRegion.getTextureRegion(0), myTiledTextureRegion.getTextureRegion(1), 
            activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                        float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                                 Toast.makeText(MenuScene.this.activity, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });

    this.attachChild(mButton);
```

**My problem is that when I Click on my button i don' t get toast message (log the same) and aslo sprite doesn't change for myTiledTextureRegion.getTextureRegion(1).** I don' t know why?

I can click on button, but there is no reaction. I tried use AnimatedSprite to test resources and it display animation correctly. Why my ButtonSprite OnClickListener and sprite change there don' work ?

Way i load resources:

```
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 512, 256, TextureOptions.NEAREST);
    myTiledTextureRegion =  BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, activity, "btn.png", 1, 3);

    try {
        mBitmapTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 1));
        mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
    } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I do everything on my Scene class, because i have only one activity (and many scenes). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see if this is the issue ... before you attach the button with `this.attachChild(mButton);` be sure and also register the touch area with `this.registerTouchArea(mButton);`

Comment: I should add that it doesn't matter if you registerTouchArea before or after adding the sprint.

Answer (score 1):

Try, after adding the sprite into the scene, to use : scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);