# ButtonSprite OnClickListener does not work

Tags: java, android

I completed my game view using add engine, but now stuck on button sprite click event.

```
ButtonSprite roll_btn;

roll_btn = new ButtonSprite(roll_btn_x, roll_btn_y, resourcesManager.roll_texture_region, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

roll_btn.setOnClickListener(new ButtonSprite.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                Log.e("@@@@@@ ","clicked "+pTouchAreaLocalX);
                Toast.makeText(cardActivity, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

this.registerTouchArea(roll_btn);
options.attachChild(roll_btn);
```

See my code.

I did not get any log on onclick and also I didn't get any error.

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an error? You'll need to be much more specific than that in order to get useful answers.

Comment: i did not get any log on onclick and also i didnt get any error, what i wrong

Comment: i made design graphycally, i loaded image from assets and displayed using texture region..my layout does not contain button code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with **this** to `options.attachChild(roll_btn);` like

```
this.attachChild(roll_btn);
```

for more [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12774002/6834114)

Comment: option is an engine, option.attachChild(roll_btn) is working. using above line button get invisible